# Getting error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.qpid.server.Main" trying to run qpid server

Tags: java, amqp, broker, qpid

This question is about the same error message:
[Apache Qpid:Error while running qpid-server.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320047/apache-qpiderror-while-running-qpid-server-bat)

my java version is:
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)

However, the solution, set the QPID_HOME environment variable is not the solution for me. My QPID_HOME is set to: QPID_HOME=C:\Progra~1\qpid-broker\8.0.6

and the directory of C:\Progra~1\qpid-broker\8.0.6\lib is:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9E21-DA19

 Directory of C:\Program Files\qpid-broker\8.0.6\lib

08/22/2022  01:47 PM    <DIR>          .
08/22/2022  01:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           684,394 bcel-6.3.1.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           115,709 bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            53,820 commons-cli-1.4.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM         3,232,770 derby-10.14.2.0.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           367,353 dgrid-1.2.1.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM        13,851,294 dojo-1.16.3-distribution.zip
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            81,254 dstore-1.1.2.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM             4,617 failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM         2,858,426 guava-30.0-jre.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            75,705 jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           365,223 jackson-core-2.12.4.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM         1,516,044 jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            95,806 javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM         3,194,359 je-7.4.5.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            25,426 jetty-continuation-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           216,515 jetty-http-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           164,646 jetty-io-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           117,779 jetty-security-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           709,109 jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           145,866 jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           107,332 jetty-servlets-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           566,323 jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            65,302 jetty-util-ajax-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           290,339 logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           471,901 logback-core-1.2.3.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           448,195 qpid-bdbstore-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            18,479 qpid-broker-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM         2,607,410 qpid-broker-core-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           110,566 qpid-broker-plugins-access-control-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           520,928 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-10-protocol-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           407,735 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           727,759 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-1-0-protocol-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            20,129 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-1-0-protocol-bdb-link-store-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            20,997 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-1-0-protocol-jdbc-link-store-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            21,544 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-msg-conv-0-10-to-1-0-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            20,209 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-msg-conv-0-8-to-0-10-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            20,410 qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-msg-conv-0-8-to-1-0-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            64,314 qpid-broker-plugins-derby-store-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            39,255 qpid-broker-plugins-jdbc-logging-logback-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            19,343 qpid-broker-plugins-jdbc-provider-bone-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           160,674 qpid-broker-plugins-jdbc-store-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           200,237 qpid-broker-plugins-logging-logback-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            65,932 qpid-broker-plugins-management-amqp-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           930,618 qpid-broker-plugins-management-http-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            39,423 qpid-broker-plugins-memory-store-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            19,326 qpid-broker-plugins-prometheus-exporter-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            31,720 qpid-broker-plugins-websocket-8.0.6.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            57,721 simpleclient-0.9.0.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM             5,823 simpleclient_common-0.9.0.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            41,472 slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            52,177 websocket-api-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM           212,494 websocket-common-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            44,836 websocket-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
11/14/2022  02:21 PM            30,263 websocket-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar
              54 File(s)     36,337,301 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  76,260,937,728 bytes free
```

I know I'm missing something, not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation it's because the CLASSPATH environment variable was set with the wrong value. Additionally, there was a QPID_CLASSPATH environment variable that was set to the same incorrect value.

Once those two environment variables were set it started as expected.